MudBlazor Table Columns not formatting correctly
I am using a MudBlazor Table to display employee information. I want the table to be condensed and horizontally scrollable, there are quite a few columns to be displayed and instead of trying to fit everything in one view/page, I want the table to overflow the columns to the right and out of view. The user can scroll horizontally to view the other columns of data. I was able to achieve something similar by wrapping the whole table in a div and using a custom css class in that tag. (Listed below as .my-table). The problem with this solution is that the mudTableToolbar and Table Pager were also affected by this class, and the tool bar and pager's content were all the way to the far right of the scrollable table. I would like only the data and header portion of the table to be scrollable. After trying other options, I am able to keep the MudTable as the size of the screen and just have the data/header be scrollable but this also breaks the columns data formatting, none of the data in the rows correctly lines up with its header. Is their some styling I am missing that can correct this? I am by no means a master of css, some help would be greatly appreciated!
Apparently I can't post images yet due to me being new to stack overflow, so some of the css I have tried will be below.
 <style>
     .my-table {
         table-layout: auto;
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: nowrap;
         white-space: nowrap;
     }

     .mud-table-row.selected-row .mud-table-cell {
         background-color: #6699CC !important;
         color: white !important;
     }
 
     .mud-table-row .mud-table-cell{
         height: auto !important;
         width: auto !important;
         padding-top: 0 !important;
         padding-bottom: 0 !important;
         line-height: 2.5 !important;
     }
 
    .mud-table-cell {
         overflow-x: auto;
         padding-top: 0;
         padding-bottom: 0;
         line-height: 2.5;
     }
    .mud-table {
         table-layout: auto;
     }


     .mud-table-row {
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: nowrap;
         white-space: nowrap;
     }
     .mud-table-header {
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: nowrap;
         white-space: nowrap;
     }


    .mud-table-header .mud-table-cell {
         height: auto;
         padding-top: 0;
         padding-bottom: 0;
         line-height: 2.5;
     }
     .mud-table-row .mud-table-header {
         align-items: center;
     }
     .mud-table-cell {
         min-width: 200px;
         flex: 2;
     }
 </style>


Please include your table aswell. Check https://mudblazor.com/components/table#horizontal-scrolling . Did you use HorizontalScrollbar="true" on the table. If not it could solve your problem
